# Laravel DB query filtering events based on selected options in <select>

Tags: php, laravel, database, filtering

So I am using Laravel and want to filter events based on user input on a filter box:

This is the filter box blade:
The

```
Request::is
```

sets the default on these pages. So `$category = 0` would be all events and `$category = 1` only the events.

```
<?php

if (Request::is('all-events')) {
    $category = '0';    
    $timeframe = '0';

} else if (Request::is('events')) {
    $category = '1';    
    $timeframe = '0';
}


if (request()->get('category')) {
    $requestCategory = request()->get('category');    

if (in_array((int)$requestCategory, range(0, 8))) {
        $category = $requestCategory;    
}
}


if (request()->get('timeframe')) {
    $requestTimeframe = request()->get('timeframe');        
    $timeframe = $requestTimeframe;
}

?>

<form class="container @if (Request::is('events')) -mt-24 @endif !pb-0">
    <div class="pt-6 md:pt-0">        
        <div class="bg-white p-6 rounded-lg">            
            <div class="grid grid-cols-1 md:grid-cols-2 gap-6">                
                <div>                    
                    <label class="mb-3 inline-block">Timeframe:</label>
                    <select aria-label="Category" name="timeframe" class="w-full bg-dark-gray p-3 rounded-lg">                        
                    <option value="0" @if ($timeframe === '0') selected @endif>Upcoming</option>                        
                    <option value="1" @if ($timeframe === '1') selected @endif>Today</option>                        
                    <option value="2" @if ($timeframe === '2') selected @endif>Tomorrow</option>                        
                    <option value="3" @if ($timeframe === '3') selected @endif>This Week</option>                        
                    <option value="4" @if ($timeframe === '4') selected @endif>Next Week</option>                        
                    <option value="5" @if ($timeframe === '5') selected @endif>Next Month</option>                    
                </select>                
            </div>               
         <div>                    
            <label class="mb-3 inline-block">Kategorie</label>                    
            <select aria-label="Kategorie" name="category" class="w-full bg-dark-gray p-3 rounded-lg">                        
                <option value="0" @if ($category === '0') selected @endif>Alle Events</option>                        
                <option value="1" @if ($category === '1') selected @endif>Events and similar</option>                        
                <option value="2" @if ($category === '2') selected @endif>Lorem Impsum</option>                        
                <option value="3" @if ($category === '3') selected @endif>Lorem Impsum</option>                        
                <option value="4" @if ($category === '4') selected @endif>Lorem Impsum</option>                        
                <option value="5" @if ($category === '5') selected @endif>Lorem Impsum</option>                        
                <option value="6" @if ($category === '6') selected @endif>Lorem Impsum</option>                        
                <option value="7" @if ($category === '7') selected @endif>Lorem Impsum</option>                        
                <option value="8" @if ($category === '8') selected @endif>Lorem Impsum</option>                   
             </select>
          </div>
      </div>            
      <div class="mt-3 flex items-end">
            <x-button type="submit" class="w-full">Suchen</x-button>
    </div>        
   </div>    
  </div>
</form>
```

This is the event controller:

```
public function eventsList(Request $request)
{
    {
        if (empty($request->query()) || $request->query('category') === '1') {
            return view('pages.course.event-list', [
                'events' => Events::query()
                    ->where('category', '1')
                    ->where('start', '>', now())
                    // add pagination                    
                    ->paginate(15)

            ]);        
         }

        if ($request->query('category') === '0') {
            return view('pages.course.event-list', [
                'events' => Events::query()
                    ->where('start', '>', now())
                    // add pagination                    
                    ->paginate(15)

            ]);       
         }

        return view('pages.course.event-list', [
            'events' => Events::query()
                ->where('category', $request->query('category'))
                ->where('start', '>', now())
                // add pagination                
             ->paginate(15)

        ]);    
}


}
```

So I could do the same like I did with the

```
$request->query('category'))
```

But like

```
$request->query('timeframe'))
```

The issue I have is I have no idea how to do this without writing spagetti code. (If cases for all cases I would have)

**Edit**:
I think that this could work but it does not get the correct dates from the DB:

```
if ($request->get('timeframe')) {
    $date = match ($request->get('timeframe')) {
        '0' => Carbon::now(),
        '1' => Carbon::today(),
        '2' => Carbon::tomorrow(),
        '3' => Carbon::now()->endOfWeek(),
        '4' => Carbon::now()->next(Carbon::MONDAY),
        '5' => Carbon::now()->startOfMonth()->addMonth()->endOfMonth(),
    };
} else {
    $date = now();
}
```

then it will use `$date` instead of `now()` in the query builder.

Comment: take a look at this package `https://spatie.be/docs/laravel-query-builder/v2/introduction`

Comment: @MohamedMelouk I dont thik that this package would help. It is possible to do this with Carbon only. The issue I now have is that it does not correctly grab / compare the dates in the query. See edit I just made.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it to work with this code in my event controller:

```
if ($request->get('timeframe')) {
    $now = CarbonImmutable::now();
    [$startDate, $endDate] = match ($request->get('timeframe')) {
        '0' => [$now, Carbon::now()->startOfMonth()->addYears('999')->endOfMonth()->endOfDay()],
        '1' => [$now , Carbon::today()->endOfDay()],
        '2' => [Carbon::tomorrow()->startOfDay(), Carbon::tomorrow()->endOfDay()],
        '3' => [$now, Carbon::now()->endOfWeek()->endOfDay()],
        '4' => [$now->next(Carbon::SUNDAY)->startOfDay(), Carbon::now()->next(Carbon::SUNDAY)->endOfDay()],
        '5' => [$now->startOfMonth()->addMonth()->startOfMonth(), Carbon::now()->startOfMonth()->addMonth()->endOfMonth()->endOfDay()],
    };
} else {
    // default if no timeframe is set as URL parameter
    $startDate = Carbon::now();
    $endDate = Carbon::now()->startOfMonth()->addYears('999')->endOfMonth()->endOfDay();
}
```

and then in the URL Query:

```
->whereBetween('start', [$startDate, $endDate])
```

Maybe there is a better solution to this, but this should work just fine?